# Laravel - Fullcalendar Loading Speed Issue for 2K+ events

Tags: php, laravel, fullcalendar, loading

I am using Fullcalendar for my app and i'm having trouble displaying the necessary events for display on calendar.

I display calendar as below;

```php
        $calendar = new Calendar();
        $calendar
        ->setOptions([
            'plugins' => ['window.interaction', 'window.dayGridPlugin', 'window.timeGridPlugin', 'window.listPlugin'],
            'locales' => 'window.allLocales',
            'locale' => config('app.locale'),
            'events' => [
                'url' => route('project_eventsJSON', ['project' => $project]),
            ],
            'firstDay' => 1,
            'timeZone' => 'local',
            'displayEventTime' => true,
            'selectable' => true,
            //'initialView' => 'timeGridWeek',
            'headerToolbar' => [
                'left' => 'prev,next today',
                'center' => 'title',
                'right' => 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
            ],
        ]);
        $calendar->setId('1');
        $calendar->setEs6();
        return $calendar;
```

and my events route as below;

```php
public function CaleventsJSON(Project $project) {
        $events = [];
foreach ($req->planneddates as $date) { 
  $event = [
                    'id' => 1,
                    'title' => $name,
                    'start' => $fullparsed,
                    'end' => $fullparsed,
                    'allDay' => true,
                ];
                $events[] = $event;

}
return response()->json($events);
}
```

Number of events is now more than 2K, i end up with crazy loading times... it takes almost 20 seconds until the events show up on calendar.

I see from my devtools that my events route(shown above) is being called as below;

```
EventsJSON?start=2022-01-31T00%3A00%3A00%2B03%3A00&end=2022-03-14T00%3A00%3A00%2B03%3A00
```

start and end dates have no effect, route still loads events from 2 years ago... i dont think i am using this correctly... how could i optimize it so that i am not loading all events and just load the events needed for display?

Thanks

Comment: `start and end dates have no affect`...well no, because you aren't using them in the php code. Where are you getting the event data from - that isn't shown in your code above? I assume it's from a database? You'll need to use the dates in a WHERE clause of your database query to restrict the results

Comment: Where is the `planneddates` in $req->planneddates defined?

Comment: @SimonK `planneddates` is a hasMany method in my model.... @ADyson - how would i   grab start and end dates from the route?

Comment: OK, show us the code where you are retrieving `$req`. I'm assuming its an eloquent query - like @ADyson says, you should be able to modify that query to filter based on the dates - just show us that code.

Comment: `    public function planneddates()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RequirementDate::class, 'req_id');
    } `

Comment: Please  use your question's "edit" button to add any extra code and information.  As you can see it's difficult  to read like that, plus it's out of context and away from the other info in the question